# How do I prevent my app rotating when the device changes orientation to landscape?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want my app to always be in portrait mode, no matter what orientation the device has.

As an example, if you have the eBay or Amazon apps, you'll see they stay in portrait mode no matter the orientation.

How can I achieve this in nativescript-vue?

Thanks!

Comment: we're gonna need some code to help you

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732970/lock-orientation-portrait-on-vuejs-pwa-for-all-browsers

Comment: Ended up finding another question here that solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410561/how-to-set-orientation-in-nativescript Look at the answers by Dean Le and Herr_Hansen